# 3D models of the unfoldings of the hypercube?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, polyhedra, polytopes

There are (apparently) 261 distinct unfoldings of the 4D hypercube, a.k.a., the
tesseract, into 3D.<sup>1</sup>
These unfoldings (or "nets") are analogous to the 11 unfoldings of
the 3D cube into the plane.<sup>2</sup>
Usually only one hypercube unfolding is illustrated,

---

[image: TesseractUnf]

         
<sup>(Image from [this link](http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/hypercube.htm).)</sup>

---

the one made famous in 
Salvador Dali's painting
*[Corpus Hypercubus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crucifixion_(Corpus_Hypercubus))*.
My question is:

> ***Q***. Has anyone made models/images of the 261 unfoldings as solid objects in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

(If not, I might do so myself.)
I previously asked [this question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/198722/6094).

---

<sup>1</sup>Peter Terney, "Unfolding the Tesseract."
*Journal of Recreational Mathematics*, Vol. 17(1), 1984-85.

---

<sup>2</sup>

[image: CubeNets]

---

Comment: Now [answered at MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/a/199003/6094).

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked and answered on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/198722/21564). I have replicated the accepted answer by Mark McClure below.

> I implemented the ideas in the paper using Mathematica.  I pushed it a bit further to actually generate the images below.  You can [download this Mathematica notebook](https://sites.google.com/a/unca.edu/mark-mcclure/UnfoldingTheTesseract.nb?attredirects=0&d=1) to see the code and detailed explanation.
>
> You might notice Dali's original in the middle of the third row from the bottom.
>
> [image]